# Информация на флешке (kingston) не отображается, хотя в настройках видно, что занято около 5 Гб. В чем может быть причина?

Tags: диск

По какой-то причине не отображается вся инфа на флешке, а только ее часть 3,5 Мб, хотя в настройках написано, что занято 5 Гб. Если кто-то сталкивался, помогите, плиз.

Comment: На самом деле, тут куча вариантов, начиная от вируса и заканчивая порчей флешки.

Comment: Попробуй chkdsk запустить, но обязательно БЕЗ режима исправления ошибок.

Comment: 1) либо отформатирован диск на 4 мб. 2) там есть скрытие системный файлы, которые в твоей ОС по умолчанию не отображаются.

Comment: Спасибо. Задача решена!